# Using remove_edge() in boost graph library and push_back to vector container

Tags: boost-graph

I just start learning boost graph library and have a basic problem on using the remove_edge function in boost graph library.

I would like to remove an edge in a multigraph. For a graph with two edges connect vertice 0 and 1, I would like to remove one of them, but kept the other.

According to the user guide, remove_edge(u ,v , g) removes all occurrences of (u ,v). So I should use remove_edge(e ,g) instead. Here, e is a valid edge descriptor.

For a single graph, g, I am able to perform both remove_edge(u ,v , g) and remove_edge(e ,g) operation without problem.

However, when I want to generalize the implementation to fit my need by putting graphs in a vector container, I got segmentation fault for remove_edge(e ,graph_list[0]). (The compiler show no warning message.) On the other hand, remove_edge(u,v,g) works perfectly. I am not sure what's the difference between those two syntax causes my problem.

I really want to make remove_edge(e,g) and vector container work at the same time. So any suggestion that can help my bypass this difficulty is appreciated.

Thanks a lot!!

Following is my test code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

#include "boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp"
#include "boost/graph/adjacency_list.
hpp"

using namespace boost;

typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS> UndirectedGraph;
typedef boost::graph_traits<UndirectedGraph>::edge_iterator edge_iterator;


int graph_show(UndirectedGraph &g);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    UndirectedGraph g;

    typedef boost::graph_traits<UndirectedGraph>::edge_descriptor edge_descriptor;
    edge_descriptor ed;

    std::vector<edge_descriptor> edge_list;
    std::vector<std::vector<edge_descriptor> > graph_edge_list;
    std::vector<UndirectedGraph> graph_list;

    int nb=0;
    int Nl=4;

    bool inserted;
    while(nb<Nl)
    {
        tie(ed,inserted)=add_edge(nb,nb+1,g);
        edge_list.push_back(ed);
        tie(ed,inserted)=add_edge(nb,nb+1,g);
        edge_list.push_back(ed);
        graph_edge_list.push_back(edge_list);
        nb=nb+1;
        graph_list.push_back(g);
    }

    std::cout<<"size of the graph vector is: "<<graph_list.size()<<std::endl;

    remove_edge(graph_edge_list[0][0],graph_list[0]);//This is where the problem shows.
                                                                           //I got Segmentation fault (core dumped)
    //remove_edge(0,1,graph_list[0]);
    /*Remove edges by assigning vertices works fine, but that is not what I need.*/

    for (int ig = 0; ig < Nl; ++ig) {
        std::cout<<"graph#"<<ig<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Size of edge_list is: "<<graph_edge_list[ig].size()<<std::endl;
        graph_show(graph_list[ig]);
    }
    std::cout<<"Success"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int graph_show(UndirectedGraph &g)
{
    std::cout<<"Number of edges is : "<<boost::num_edges(g)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Number of vertices is : "<<boost::num_vertices(g)<<std::endl;
    std::pair<edge_iterator,edge_iterator> ei=edges(g);

    for (edge_iterator edge_iter = ei.first; edge_iter!=ei.second; ++edge_iter) {
            std::cout<<"("<< boost::source(*edge_iter,g)<<","<<boost::target(*edge_iter,g)<<")"<<std::endl;
    }

    typedef boost::graph_traits<UndirectedGraph>::vertex_iterator iter_v;

    std::cout<<"vertices(g)={ ";
    for (std::pair<iter_v,iter_v> p = vertices(g); p.first != p.second; ++p.first) {
            std::cout<< *p.first;
                std::cout<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<"}"<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind when using vecS and removing stuff, it invalidates your iterators and indexes. Removing is much easier when you use ListS in BGL. Check out [iterator and descriptor stability/invalidity](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html)

Comment: At first I think it is because of the invalidation of edge_descriptor. However, I tried to remove edge on a single graph g, and I can remove edge by both remove_edge(u,v,g) and remove_edge(e,g). Also, if I did not use push_back to copy g to the vector container, everything works fine. Another reason that I don't think it is because of the edge descriptor invalidation is the line I got seg fault is the remove_edge(e,g). If it is because edge descriptor invalidation, I would expect things to be wrong when I try to print out the edges which require the valid edge descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but I tried the code and it seems like the problem comes at:

```
g.m_edges.erase(edge_iter_to_erase);
```

in adjacency_list.hpp on line 771.

This seems like a bug. You may want to check the boost mailing list.

The context is:

```
 template <>
  struct remove_undirected_edge_dispatch<no_property> {
    // O(E/V)
    template <class edge_descriptor, class Config>
    static void
    apply(edge_descriptor e,
          undirected_graph_helper<Config>& g_,
          no_property&)
    {
      typedef typename Config::global_edgelist_selector EdgeListS;
      BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((!is_same<EdgeListS, vecS>::value));

      typedef typename Config::graph_type graph_type;
      graph_type& g = static_cast<graph_type&>(g_);
      no_property* p = (no_property*)e.get_property();
      typename Config::OutEdgeList& out_el = g.out_edge_list(source(e, g));
      typename Config::OutEdgeList::iterator out_i = out_el.begin();
      typename Config::EdgeIter edge_iter_to_erase;
      for (; out_i != out_el.end(); ++out_i)
        if (&(*out_i).get_property() == p) {
          edge_iter_to_erase = (*out_i).get_iter();
          out_el.erase(out_i);
          break;
        }
      typename Config::OutEdgeList& in_el = g.out_edge_list(target(e, g));
      typename Config::OutEdgeList::iterator in_i = in_el.begin();
      for (; in_i != in_el.end(); ++in_i)
        if (&(*in_i).get_property() == p) {
          in_el.erase(in_i);
          break;
        }
      g.m_edges.erase(edge_iter_to_erase);
    }
  };
```

When I step through with the debugger, it shows that `edge_iter_to_erase = (*out_i).get_iter();` is never executed. This causes the undefined behavior when calling vector's [erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) method since the position is invalid (I am guessing).

If you use just `g` instead of `graph_list[0]` it works fine as well.

Take a look [here](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/BGL-remove-edge-with-vecS-for-vertices-and-setS-for-edges-td2563732.html) for a similar problem on the mailing list. They use a different adjacency_list.

If I alter the graph to be:

```
typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS,no_property,no_property,no_property,setS> UndirectedGraph;
```

as in that post. I get an access read violation instead of a seg fault.

Seems like a bug, but I have no idea why it does this for the vector referenced graph and not the variable g.

Comment: Thanks a lot! After several attempts to understand the question. I think the problem came from the push_back part to vector container. If I assume I have a graph_list with known size and declare it at first, then operations can be performed correctly. So I think I have two options now...1) find a way to initiate the containers dynamically without using push_back. 2) Some smart way to push_back the graph to vector container without destroy the corresponding pointer/reference structure. I am not sure which one is easier to me...

Comment: I'm still puzzled as to why push_back causes the problem. This should not happen. I even tried to make UndirectedGraph copies using copy_graph and still got the strange behavior. I typically use pointer's to graphs so I don't have to worry about pass by value issues. That may be worth trying too.